# displaying a row from mysql

Tags: php

I have a slight issue atm. I have been given two tables. I have one table which has an ID column and a country column. The ID is the primary key for the countries. In the other table, I have the ID and other numerous bits of information. I have created a dynamic drop down list which selects the country and saves it as a variable which is then POSTED to another page. How can I select the ID for that country and then display frmo the rest of the columns in that table in PHP.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the value that is sent in `POST` will contain the country name?

If so, then try following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.Country_ID 
WHERE t1.country = '$country'
```

table1 is your table with the country and the ID, table2 is the second table with more fields. `$country` holds the country name.